# Nextjs dynamic routing not working in firebase hosting

Tags: firebase, routes, next.js, hosting, firebase-hosting

I have a dynamic router `job/[jobId]` but it doesn't work after hosting. I don't know how to write the `rewrites` in `firebase.json` for this as well. Here's my rewrites.

Currently firebase throws 404 if I access a page such as `job/2` page

Output structure

```
├── job
│   └── [jobId]
│       └── index.html
```

pages structure

```
.
├── _app.js
├── _document.js
├── careers
│   └── index.js
├── index.js
├── job
│   └── [jobId].js
└── privacy.js
```

Rewrites

```
"rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "job/**",
        "destination": "job/[jobId]/index.html"
      }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
"rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "/job/**",
        "destination": "/job/[jobId]/index.html"
      }
```

Starting `/` was missing

Comment: Your answer helped me. thank you.

Comment: I am having a very similar issue (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77936270/nextjs-dynamic-links-firebase), but this doesn't seem to  work for me, unless I am missing something.

Answer (score 3):

While facing the same issue, I encountered a discussion here which was very helpful in understanding how Firebase and Next.js interact, and therefore what solution I would need to use.

https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/discussions/4980

The summary of what helped me can be found on that link, but I'll include it here for completeness.

- Add `trailingSlash: true,` to [next.js.config](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/trailing-slash)

  - This lets all static routing work (i.e. routes without a "slug")
- Add dynamic / "slug" routes to the rewrites section of firebase.json

Relevant excerpt from firebase.json:

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "target": "my-app",
    "public": "frontend/out",
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "destination": "/job/[jobId]/index.html",
        "regex": "^/job/([^/]+?)(?:/)?$"
      },
    ]
  },
}
```

Here is a gist of a utility script that can grab all of your dynamic slug routes from the .next folder, and place them in firebase.json automatically (mostly for CI related use cases).

https://gist.github.com/jeff-r-koyaltech/6195f546764443d0cc7c5efe48fbe896